# Hide "Export PDF, Create PDF, etc" Pane and Keep It Hidden

Tags: vb.net, pdf, visual-studio-2017, axacropdf

This is such a small thing that's been such a pain to deal with. I'm expecting there's a simple answer that's simply evaded my searching, I just don't know what it is!!

Purpose:
The program is a fancy document viewer as part of a troubleshooting guide. It pulls up a PDF based on the problem a customer is having, as well as links to related PDFs.

Problem:
It works just fine at first. The documents open up and look pretty and all that (see first picture below). However, if the same document is opened twice in a single session--which i expect to be a common occurrence--this tool pane thing appears, shrinking the document itself and overall just looking awful (see second picture below).

Process:
I've looked around a lot, I've checked all the variables for AxAcroPDF, but neither setShowToolbar(False) nor setPageMode("None") have helped. I've also tried using a "refresh" button to reload the PDF without closing the window, but that doesn't appear to do anything of use. 
Is there another property I'm missing? Also, is it weird that it only happens the second time a document is opened, and never the first?

Good Version:
[image: PDF Opens the first time without issue--it looks great]

Bad Version:
[image: Closing and opening the document leads to the whole right-side pane opening up.]

Answer (score 1):

I've recently encountered the same problem as well and tried every other solution on the internet but to no avail.

I didn't force using axacropdf anymore instead I used a web browser control. 
Put it in the your form in replace of the adobe pdf reader and put this in code;

`WebBrowser1.Navigate(yourFileLocation + "#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0")`

This will view the pdf in full screen even if you view the same document the second time around.